# Parallel STL algorithms in OS X

Tags: macos, algorithm, stl, parallel-processing

I working on converting an existing program to take advantage of some parallel functionality of the STL.

Specifically, I've re-written a big loop to work with std::accumulate.  It runs, nicely.

Now, I want to have that accumulate operation run in parallel.

The documentation I've seen for GCC outline two specific steps.

1. Include the compiler flag `-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL`
2. Possibly add the header `<parallel/algorithm>`

Adding the compiler flag doesn't seem to change anything.  The execution time is the same, and I don't see any indication of multiple core usage when monitoring the system.

I get an error when adding the parallel/algorithm header.  I thought it would be included with the latest version of gcc (4.7).

So, a few questions:

1. Is there some way to definitively determine if code is actually running in parallel?
2. Is there a "best practices" way of doing this on OS X?  (Ideal compiler flags, header, etc?)

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this.  Doesn't this page answer your question though?: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt12ch31s03.html

Comment: OS X's `gcc` coming from Xcode is 4.2, not 4.7. (Or you could use clang, but I don't know if libc++ has the parallel algorithms)

Comment: Kenny, you are correct.  However, I'm also using Cmake to generate traditional make files and then gcc 4.7 to compile them (from the command line.)  Still no evidence of parallelism.

Comment: @ergosys.  That is the exact page I'm following which gave rise to my two questions.  <parallel/algorithm> isn't included on my machine, and the "global" parallelize flag doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: How do you know that the makefiles are running gcc 4.7?  Try #include <parallel/algorithm> in a "hello world" program compiled from the command line to make sure at least that works.  I don't have a Mac at this time, but this works for 4.6.1 on linux, so 4.7 should have these headers installed as well.  If the mac installation is anything like linux, you will need to use something like g++-4.7 hello.cpp to compile.  My guess is cmake isn't configured to do that and is using the gcc installed with xcode.

Comment: @ergosys It looks like you are correct.  Calling g++ hello.cpp from the command line with that include does work.  So it looks like cmake isn't using the correct compiler.  Nice!

Comment: If you have the Intel 18 compiler, it supports PSTL for Mac, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516385/2189128).  A link in that post is for the free beta download, which is available for another month or two.

Answer (score 2):

See http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/

If you only ever parallelize STL algorithms, you are going to disappointed in the results in general.  Those algorithms generally only begin to show a scalability advantage when working over very large datasets (e.g. N > 10 million).

TBB (and others like it) work at a higher level, focusing on the overall algorithm design, not just the leaf functions (like std::accumulate()).

Answer (score 0):

- Second alternative is to use OpenMP, which is supported by both GCC and
  Clang, though is not STL by any means, but is cross-platform.
- Third alternative is to use Grand Central Dispatch - the official multicore API in OSX, again hardly STL.
- Forth alternative is to wait for C++17, it will have Parallelism module.

Comment: Six years later, I have the same question: C++17 is (almost) here, I see wording in N4618 for "parallel algorithms", but I can't figure out how to use them yet on any major and/or free-as-in-beer compiler. I don't know if they're unimplemented or if I just haven't worked out the magic `-D`s yet.

Comment: You can look here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SyclParallelSTL or https://github.com/intel/parallelstl but I've noticed that par algorithm are really slow, more than sequential one

Comment: Just wanna jump in and suggest https://github.com/mikekazakov/pstld. Works like a drop-in replacement and behind the scenes utilizes `libdispatch`.
Been using it for a while and so far so good (haven't personally profiled extensively).