# How to use experimental parallel STL in C++1z?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17, libc++

I want to try parallel STL of C++17. However, I can't find experimental/execution_policy in libc++. How can I try this?

I'm trying http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reduce, which says I should include these files, but I cannot find execution_policy.

```
#include <experimental/execution_policy>
```

After I install libc++ (I followed http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html), I tried the following commands, but in vain.

```
$ clang++-3.5 -std=c++1z test.cpp -lc++experimental
test.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'experimental/execution_policy' file not found
#include <experimental/execution_policy>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Is this not implemented yet?

Comment: It looks like 3.5 is too old version of clang.

Comment: Neither libstdc++, libc++, nor MSVC's stdlib has the C++17 parallel algorithms yet. [HPX](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx) is your best bet for using them now.

Comment: What you are looking at is the technical specification for parallelism library extensions, which predates C++17. In C++17 it (will be) `#include <execution>`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce#Example --

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you for your recommendation. I think it's too early to try this, but it was a good opportunity to know such projects are ongoing :)

Comment: @Cubbi Thank you. I'll try them when c++17 is released!

Comment: Late addition: Intel C++ 18.0 will have a full implementation of the parallel algorithms. :-D It's in beta presently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this not implemented yet?

That is correct. Neither the parallelism TS (which would live in `<experimental/xxx>` or the parallel algorithms in the (not yet final) C++1z standard have been implemented in libc++ (yet).

Comment: Ah, I thought c++1z would be the same as c++17. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RyoWakatabe : It is (or will be barring some catastrophe) ; but the new standard is not yet finalized so is not _technically yet_ "C++17". For now, _technically_, the only released specification for parallelism is the TS.

Comment: This answer should be updated because it is now false.

Answer (score 3):

I use the implementation of PSTL in [Intel 18 Parallel Studio XE beta](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-2018-beta), which composes with both libc++ and libstdc++ and is based on [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org).  I've tested `for_each` and `transform` but nothing else.

Update: The Intel PSTL is open-source (https://github.com/intel/parallelstl) and works with GCC and Clang.

Update 2: The Intel PSTL is part of GCC 9.1 ([release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html), [commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=7e155e541f4a871d3bbd686506580cad62b18e25)) and LLVM ([commit](https://reviews.llvm.org/D55889)).

Because support for PSTL is not ubiquitous, I make the [code](https://github.com/ParRes/Kernels/blob/master/Cxx11/transpose-vector-pstl.cc) portable via the preprocessor:

```
#if defined(USE_PSTL) && defined(__INTEL_COMPILER) && (__INTEL_COMPILER >= 1800)
  std::for_each( pstl::execution::par, std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int i) {
    std::for_each( pstl::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int j) {
#elif defined(USE_PSTL) && defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_MINOR__) \
                        && ( (__GNUC__ == 8) || (__GNUC__ == 7) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ >= 2) )
  __gnu_parallel::for_each( std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int i) {
    __gnu_parallel::for_each( std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int j) {
#else
#warning Parallel STL is NOT being used!
  std::for_each( std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int i) {
    std::for_each( std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&] (int j) {
#endif
        B[i*order+j] += A[j*order+i];
        A[j*order+i] += 1.0;
      });
    });
  }
```

You can see that this code is based on `libc++` on Mac, although the PSTL part itself is from the Intel headers, which in turn use TBB as the runtime.

```
$ otool -L transpose-vector-pstl
transpose-vector-pstl:
    @rpath/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
    @rpath/libiomp5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

Full disclosure: I work for Intel and have discussed this implementation with the developers, although I am in no way responsible for it.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Jeff's answer ...

Both GCC and Clang now include the Intel PSTL implementation in order to provide the C++17 parallel algorithms in their C++ standard libraries.

At the time of writing, there is an additional dependency on the Intel TBB library, which the PSTL uses as its backend to provide parallelism.